# remove all texnode from createdTextNode

Tags: javascript, dhtml

```
for (var x in myOpts) {
    if(myOpts.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        var t = document.createElement("OPTION");
        t.setAttribute("id",x);
        t.value = x;
        t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(myOpts[x]));
        selectObj.appendChild(t);
    }
}
```

how proper clear or delete createdTextNodes ???

```
if (document.getElementById( 'rolec' )) {
    var rd = document.getElementById( 'rolec' );
    while (rd.firstChild) {
        rd.removeChild(rd.firstChild);
    }
}
```

With this only first and it empty value

Comment: You're missing a `}` in that last snippet first of all.

Comment: first of all looks like `t.setAttribute("id","rolec");` could end up would multiple id's in the same document.

Answer (score 0):

If I properly understand your question, you have to iterate a list of child nodes in reverse order to remove them all one by one;

```
var rdChildren = rd.childNodes;
for( i = ( rdChildren.length - 1 ); i >= 0; i-- )
{
    rd.removeChild( rdChildren[i] );
}
```

DOM node lists are "live" meaning they update as you manipulate the DOM. So to catch them all you have to run backwards. ;)